# accessor function in class type not returning proper values from private data in c++

Tags: c++

I currently have a comp sci project related to poker. I have a class called Card and my constructor is working properly but I am not sure if I am accessing my private data properly when trying to print out the card details.

the cards are stored as a `typedef enum (Invalid, Diamonds, Clubs... ) cSuit`

constructor inputs the data into private data variable `cSuit m_suit`;

I have 3 member functions 1 is `Card::cSuit Card::suit` (returns the suit)

`Card::cPoints Card::points` (which returns the point of the card)
and a `Void Card::print` (which prints the cards out nicely)

when I print out of the cards they all come out as invalid. I have used cout to throughout my code to see where the issue is and I think it is in my print function any suggestion is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "card.h"

using namespace std ;


// Default constructor marks card as invalid // 
Card::Card() {    m_suit = Invalid ;    m_points = 0 ; }


Card::Card(cSuit s, cPoints p) {

  // your code goes here   
if (s >=1 && s <=4){

    m_suit = s ;   }   else {
    m_suit = Invalid;
    m_points = 0;   }   if (p >=2 && p <=14){
    m_points = p;   }   else {
    m_points = 0 ;
    m_suit = Invalid;   } }


Card::cPoints Card::points() {

  // your code goes here   
cPoints cardPoints;   cardPoints = m_points;    return cardPoints; }

Card::cSuit Card::suit() {

  // your code goes here  


cSuit cardSuit;   cardSuit = m_suit;   return cardSuit; }


void Card::print() {

  // your code goes here  
 Card cardPoint;   Card cardSuits;

  if (cardPoint.points() >=2 && cardPoint.points() <= 10){
    cout << cardPoint.points() << " of " << cardSuits.suit() << endl;   }   if (cardPoint.points() == 11){ 
    cout << "Jack of " << cardSuits.suit() << endl;   }   if (cardPoint.points() == 12){
    cout << "Queen of " << cardSuits.suit() << endl;   }   if (cardPoint.points() == 13){
    cout << "Kind of " << cardSuits.suit() << endl;   }   if (cardPoint.points() == 14) {
    cout << "Ace of " << cardSuits.suit() << endl;}   else {
    cout << "Invalid card" << endl; } }
```

what would be the proper way to print out my cards.

if I am not asking my questions properly please give me tips because unfortunately the last time I asked my question was not well received.

Comment: Badly formatted code will certainly get you down votes.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the print method you declare two variables, cardPoint and cardSuits, which you later use to print information. The problem is, you create them with default constructors and they aren't related in any way to the card you want to call print() on. I can't help any further without seeing the rest of Card class, so if you need more explanation, you'll have to post the whole class code.

Comment: Do you know how I would call those private data members using my accessor variables to print them out?

Answer (score 0):

`cardSuits` and `cardPoints` are default initialized local objects, and thus only exist in your function.

You want to access the actual members. You do this by writing `this->(name_of_member)`. This member can be public, protected, or private, doesn't matter. This member can be a member function (`this->function()`) or a data member (`this->data`). Writing `this->` is optional but makes your intent explicit.

So everywhere, where you write `cardPoint.(...)` or `cardSuit.(...)`, try writing `this->(...)` instead.

Comment: would (...) be the data member? how would I exactly refer to it? I dont understand your reply properly sorry. I do understand how cardPoints is a local object. I will try to work around that thanks.

Comment: Actually it can be any member. So you could call `this->suit()` or `this->m_suit`.

Comment: So I just tried that but for some reason everything still prints out as Invalid :(

Comment: Because you're comparing `Card::cPoints` with `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I see more code, I can say more. To print the card, you should remove `Card cardPoint;` and `Card cardSuits;` from the print() function, and just use `m_suit` and `m_points`, the print() method will have no problem with them being private, since it's a member function. I mean, just write `cout << m_points << " of " << m_suit << endl;` and it'll work.

I also see what's probably a bug in the `Card::Card(cSuit s, cPoints p)` constructor - think what happens when you call it with s == Invalid and p == 2. Plus, the `Card::cPoints Card::points()` function is unnecessarily complicated - you can just `return m_points;`.

And you should really learn to format your code...

EDIT: I see another reason why it always prints "Invalid card" - in the print function, you use multiple `if` statements, where you should use `else if`:

```
if (m_points >=2 && m_points <= 10){...}
else if (m_points == 11){...}
else if (m_points == 12){...}
else if (m_points == 13){...}
else if (m_points == 14) {...}
else { cout << "Invalid card" << endl; }
```

In your version, without `else if`'s it just executes `if` statements one after another, at the end it reaches `if(m_points == 14)`, whish is false in most cases, so it goes to `else` statement, and prints 'Invalid card'